# PouchDB replicate returns a silent error

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm really new to couch/pouch so I'll strictly point the question: I have a couch server that contains a _users database and for every user inside I built a personal DB (this works well). In an AngularJS app, I need to sync (one way from server to client) a pouchDB. This is my code:

```
if($.isEmptyObject(server_params)) {
    throw "Server Params not initialized";
}

var remote_connection_string = server_params.protocol + db_name + ":" + passwd + "@" + server_params.domain + "/" + db_name;
var allow_origin_object = {};

if (server_params.origin) {
    allow_origin_object = {
        fetch: function (url, opts) {
            opts.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', server_params.origin);
            return pouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
        }
    };
}

var local_db = new pouchDB({
    auto_compaction: true,
    name: db_name
});
var remote_db = new pouchDB(remote_connection_string, allow_origin_object);

var handler = local_db.replicate.from(remote_db, {});
handler.on('change', function (info) {
    console.log(info, arguments);
}).on('paused', function (err) {
    console.log(err, arguments);
}).on('active', function () {
    console.log("Active!", arguments);
}).on('denided', function (err) {
    console.log(err, arguments);
}).on('complete', function (info) {
    console.log(info, arguments);
}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err, arguments);
}).then(function () {
    console.log("then - resolve: ", arguments);
}, function () {
    console.log("then - reject: ", arguments);
}).finally(function () {
    console.log("finally: ", arguments);
});
```

At execution time I get the console.log in the error section (seen from script line number) and the fail 'then' respectively with this response:

```
t {result: {…}}
  result:
    doc_write_failures: 0
    docs_read: 0
    docs_written: 0
    end_time: "2018-07-16T14:58:15.832Z"
    errors: Array(0)
      length: 0
      __proto__: Array(0)
    last_seq: 0
    ok: false
    start_time: "2018-07-16T14:58:15.828Z"
    status: "aborting"
    __proto__: Object
  __proto__: Error

Arguments [t, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
  0: t {result: {…}} //same as before
  callee: ƒ (err)
  length: 1
  Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
  __proto__: Object

then - reject: Arguments [t, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
                 0: t {result: {…}} //Same as before
                 callee: ƒ ()
                 length: 1
                 Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
                 __proto__: Object
```

Finally, this is the couchDB server log at the execution time:

```
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:14.936265Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27495.232> ace657cb79 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 2
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:14.938101Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27714.232> 0f8058a082 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:15.643560Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27421.232> 7109b0fe1c 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:15.644622Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.29430.232> 62ae5b985c 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 0
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:15.676596Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27058.232> 525bfaef78 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:15.677802Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27216.232> a5bfb296e2 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:15.729505Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27325.232> 3a7ef79eee 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 5
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:15.730669Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27271.232> 859e6a7a77 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:15.899331Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.29372.232> bab85b4599 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 2
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:15.900569Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.29451.232> a7814fa0d6 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.194140Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27487.232> a33e1cf89a 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 2
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.195184Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27437.232> d83fa88258 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.374816Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27374.232> 7e3181a5fe 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 2
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.375180Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.26122.232> 63dd14607c 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 2
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.376273Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.26973.232> dbe6cbfbfe 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 0
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.377752Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.26655.232> 1dc92196a6 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 0
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.380779Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.26974.232> 6f551e8c54 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 4
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.381229Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.21323.232> ff863db7bb 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 4
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.382777Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.26610.232> 05aed374e1 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.382818Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.23204.232> 0177b5a85c 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.383940Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.26937.232> a62c233ddc 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-a713a2af2eb25c57ba17548 409 ok 5
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.384476Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27032.232> e7938336f1 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94 409 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.384887Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.26874.232> 3bc9bbc043 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-a713a2af2eb25c57ba17548/_security 200 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.385498Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.26751.232> b1644014a0 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-dbba7695d17cdec2cc6dc94/_security 200 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.387350Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.27782.232> 9dd4b8a07e 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Auser-5cd8241f12f4f91ba20feb3 409 ok 1
[notice] 2018-07-16T14:58:16.388264Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.26625.232> eec2e12357 127.0.0.1:5984 127.0.0.1 client GET /user-5cd8241f12f4f91ba20feb3/_security 200 ok 0
```

Of course the sync fails. Some help? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your remote_connection _string has the correct format? If your remote database has a user name and password it should look like:

```
https://username:password@hostname/databasename
```

but in your code it looks like you have:

```
https://databasename:password@hostname
```

so I think it is worth checking that you can return the basic database info before trouble-shooting the possible replication issues.

Comment: you're rigth, but it is a transcription error, just one of my tests. I have editided the post to reflect the correct string, but the result is the same

Comment: P.S.: In my case db_name and username are the same

Comment: It might be worth just doing a simple test to return the db.info() from the remote database if you have not done that yet. I can see other problems with the code - PouchDB is not capitalised correctly for example. So it is difficult to troubleshoot the replication problem if this is not the code you are using. Could you add the latest code to your question?